# Do recursive methods in ES6 classes take advantage of TCO (Tail Call Optimization)?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, tail-recursion

So I have read that ECMAScript6 (ES6) is capable of TCO.  I have seen this demonstrated as: *(crude example with no practical purpose...)*

```
const tcoFn = (acc) => {
  if (acc > 10) {
    return acc
  } else {
    return tcoFn(acc + 1)
  }
}
```

My question is whether or not it is known that we get TCO in an ES6 class?  So,

```
class TCOish {
  tcoMethod(acc) {
    if (acc > 10) {
      return acc
    } else {
      return tcoMethod(acc + 1)
    }
  }
} // End class definition
```

After some searching on the Interwebs this remains unclear to me and I am wondering if there is a definitive answer that someone can point me to?

Also worth noting is that this will be used in Node app where we do not care about the browser or transpiling.

Thank you.

Comment: It's not implemented in node

Comment: https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: Testing for this optimization is simple. Just run your function with an immense amount of recursion, and if you get a "too much recursion" error, then it isn't.

Comment: Thanks everyone - knowing where to look is always helpful.  Hat tip to Andy for the link - that's a pretty awesome visual representation of feature support in this space.

Comment: It needs to be `this.tcoMethod(…)`

Comment: Relevant Chromium bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4698

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,from the [link](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) that Andy provided in the comments above, it looks like the answer is not yet.  This seems to be generally true excepting WebKit which is a bit ahead in the TCO arena.  Worth noting is that the value of this "answer" will degrade over time as TCO support grows.